# Как обойти cloudflare с selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Как обойти cloudflare с selenium? Работаю на пайтоне. Вообще возможно ли его обойти? Очень нужна помощь

Answer (score 1):

Если ты знаешь настоящий ip сайта, то к нему и обращайся.

Если ты не знаешь настоящий ip, тоты его узнать не можешь, а значит обойти не получится.